# Understanding Python Websockets

Tags: python, websocket

Apologies in advance for the vague questions. I am trying to understand Websockets.

Is the webserver a different process from the WebSocket server?

If I have one webpage that is being viewed by different client browsers, and I send new data via the socket server, do all the viewing clients get updates via a single message, or do I have to send one message per client?

If I have multiple pages receiving updates from sockets; do I need one socket server per page or can I use one socket server to send to multiple pages? E.G  send "YES" to /page1.html  and send "NO" to  /page2.html using one socket server process?

Answer (score 1):

Websocket is on client site like a listener. And on Server site like a sender.

The Websocket client is listening to the socket. And multiple clients can listen the same socket. This happens by connect to a specific socket from client site.

To distinguish which message should be process by a client and which not, the socket could send an "identifier" in the package, which will be ignored from the pages which should do nothing.